# I cannot select "from city" in MakeMyTrip website with Selenium WebDriver. It does not select the specified city by entering the text "che"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to Handle Auto Suggestive Dropdowns in this website
https://www.makemytrip.com/   by using selenium webdriver in eclipse

At the time of running this test case in Selenium Webdriver i am not getting any exceptions,but i am not getting expected results what i am looking from that website through this test execution.

```
package udemyClasses;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class AutoSuggestiveDropdowns {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();      
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");  
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement f=driver.findElement(By.id("fromCity"));     
        f.sendKeys("che");      
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        f.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        f.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);     
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        f.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement t=driver.findElement(By.id("toCity"));       
        t.sendKeys("del");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        t.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);        
        t.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(2000);     
    }
}
```

Actually i am expecting in that page "from city" is selected as Chennai and "to city" is selected as Delhi.But they didn't select any city in "from city" and "to city" dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.
You can use the xpath to select the city as shown below.

```
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");  
Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement f=driver.findElement(By.id("fromCity"));     
f.sendKeys("che");      
Thread.sleep(2000);
f.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'hsw_autocomplePopup')]//p[contains(.,'Chennai') and contains(@class,'font16')]")).click();
WebElement t=driver.findElement(By.id("toCity"));       
t.sendKeys("del");
Thread.sleep(2000);
f.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'hsw_autocomplePopup')]//p[contains(.,'Delhi') and contains(@class,'font16')]")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Not convinced with the `Thread.sleep(2000)` within this answer while answering to a _New contributor_ where as in your other answers you use **WebDriverWait**

Comment: My focus of this answer was on the issue mentioned in the Original post. OP, has to take care of the hard coded `Time.Sleep()`.